# Errror while fitting knn

Tags: r

I was trying to fit a knn model to my data set

the dimensions of training and test set are as follows: dim(trainX)
 1176   22

> dim(testX)
>   [1] 294  22
>   dim(trainy)
>   [1] 1176    1
>   dim(testy)
>   [1] 294   1

pred1 = knn(train=trainX,test= testX,cl=trainy,k=1)

Error in knn(train = trainX, test = testX, cl = trainy, k = 1) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Comment: post code if you want debugging help

Comment: Pretty sure `dim(trainy)` and `dim(testy)` should be `NULL`, since they're supposed to be vectors.

Comment: Which packages are you using and on what data? Use `dput` or `str` of the datasets to provide a "glimpse" of your data.